# Python sqlalchemy update row with variable issues

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to update an sqlalchemy database.  It throws an error based off the string I try to implement into the query. I dont want to hardcode the link, but rather use the variable as I am looping through my database.

```
print (u)
(u'http://32rfckwuorlf4dlv.ca/linklist/1-general\n',)


currentlink = (str(u)[:-3][1:])
print currentlink
u'http://32rfckwuorlf4dlv.ca/linklist/1-general\n'
```

This fails..

```
x = Item.query.filter_by(link=currentlink).first()
            print x
            try:
                print x.id
                x.title = 'test'
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))

            db.session.commit()
```

prints :'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

This works..

```
x =  Item.query.filter_by(link=u'http://32rfckwuorlf4dlv.ca/linklist/1-general\n').first()

            print x
            try:
                print x.id
                x.title = 'test'
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))

            db.session.commit()
```

prints: http://32rfckwuorlf4dlv.ca/linklist/1-general\n'>
prints: 90

Comment: Well yea there's a row in your database with `link = 'http://32rfckwuorlf4dlv.ca/client-check\n'` but no row with `link = 'http://32rfckwuorlf4dlv.ca/linklist/1-general\n'`.

Comment: Used wrong link example..i believe it has to do with the way \n is represented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the reason is that `currentlink` is actually `"u'http://32rfckwuorlf4dlv.ca/linklist/1-general\\n"`, not `u'http://32rfckwuorlf4dlv.ca/linklist/1-general\n'`.

Assuming `u` is a `tuple`, you should do

```
currentlink = u[0]
```

instead.

If you want to make your example work (not recommended by the way, it's only for edification purposes):

```
currentlink = str(u)[:-3][3:].replace("\\n", "\n")
```

If `u` is a `str` instead, you need to figure out why it's a `str` instead of a `tuple`.

Answer (score 1):

two things

1. seems the variable `u` in your description is a tuple, so you can just use `currentlink = u[0]` to get the url link.
2. The currentlink **u'http://32rfckwuorlf4dlv.ca/linklist/1-general\n'** and **http://32rfckwuorlf4dlv.ca/client-check\n** in hardcode are different. And I think this is the reason that you get a Nonetype from database.